# Does PayPal reveal your bank account and debit (credit) card details?

Tags: paypal

I recently joined this microwork website Clickworker, I'll get paid via PayPal so they asked me to add my PayPal account, that is, the e-mail account linked to my PayPal account. I don't have a PayPal account yet so I'm about to open one, but I'm not sure about letting PayPal share my bank account and debit card details with other parties, I just want to know:

Will PayPal share bank account and debit (credit) card details with Clickworker (or anyone else) or is it just my e-mail address they will see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They just see your email address and in some cases your address (for shipping). [Source](https://www.paypal.me/pages/faqs) and [another Source](https://www.paypal.com/ca/webapps/mpp/home) (scroll down to "There are lots of other reasons to use PayPal.")

Answer (score 3):

No, PayPal will not share bank account and debit (credit) card details with anyone else; it is just your e-mail and mailing addresses they will see.